# sphere not showing in opengl

Tags: opengl

here is my display method:

```
void display()
{
    GLfloat sphere_vertices[3]={0.0,0.0,0.0};

    int theta,phi;
    float x,y,z;
    int off_set;
    off_set=5;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

   for (theta=-90; theta<=90-off_set; theta+=off_set) {
      for (phi=0; phi<=360-off_set; phi+=off_set) 
        {
            //calculate X of sphere 
            x= cos(theta + off_set) * sin(phi + off_set);
            //calculate Y of sphere
            y = cos(theta + off_set) * cos(theta + off_set);
            //calculate Z of sphere 
            z = sin(theta + off_set);
            //store vertices
            sphere_vertices[0]=x;
            sphere_vertices[1]=y;
            sphere_vertices[2]=z;
            //plot new point            
            glVertex3fv(sphere_vertices);
            printf("X is %f, Y is %f, Z is %f",  x,y,z);
        }
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

}
```

I am calculating the points on the surface of a sphere and then plotting each point. But the only thing I get are some pixel at the bottom-left corner of the screen

Comment: You didn't write what is your viewing matrix, please add it to your question.

Note that cos and sin take input parameters in radians, not degrees.

Comment: glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluOrtho2D(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 50.0);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

Comment: what exactly is a viewing matrix? I am pretty new to OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to render a sphere with radius of 1.0 consisting of about `180 / off_set` slices of circles with `360 / off_set` points. How did you come up with your x, y and z?

For each point, you could construct a unit length vector on, for example, the xy-plane from `theta` and then rotate it about the z-axis by `phi` and scale the resulting vector by the radius of the sphere.

After reviewing your math, make sure you have specified the model-view and projection matrices and note if you are using the standard cos/sin functions, they take radians, not degrees.